# cmake: pkg_check_modules libusb version

Tags: cmake, libusb, pkg-config, libusb-1.0

I have two versions of libusb installed:

```
$ pkg-config --libs libusb
-lusb
$ pkg-config --libs libusb-1.0
-lusb-1.0
```

For a project I want to use the libusb-1.0 version, hence I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
pkg_check_modules(LIBUSB REQUIRED libusb-1.0)
```

However, the resulting variable that I use for linking `${LIBUSB_LIBRARIES}` contains only `usb`, not `usb-1.0`. So basically I'm linking against the wrong library. Why is that so? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be that those are not meant to be installed at together and you get those errors because of that.

Comment: Well, on my Ubuntu these two live happily besides each other (I even believe they were there by default, but I'm not sure anymore). What puzzles me is that CMake apparently strips off the "-1.0", even though `pkg-config` outputs the correct name.

Comment: I am not sure which command `pkg_check_modules` executes. Have you checked what `LIBUSB_VERSION ` version says?

Comment: In [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPkgConfig.html) `pkg_check_modules` is applied to `glib-2.0` library, so suffix is unlikely is a problem. Have you tried clean configuration? If you used similar call for `libusb` before, some of its `LIBUSB_*` variables could be cached, so new call doesn't update them.

Comment: I think I found the problem. It has to do with the prefix `LIBUSB`, that I gave in the `pkg_check_modules` command. It turns out that all these variables `LIBUSB_*` are already defined, even if I omit the `pkg_check_modules` command. If I use another prefix, like `pkg_check_modules(LU REQUIRED libusb-1.0)`, it works fine. Which leads me to the question: why are the `LIBUSB_*` variables already defined? Is there another already existing prefix for the 1.0 version?

Comment: @Tsyvaref: That could very well be the reason! Is there a simpler way to tidy up the configuration than manually deleting all files and folders that CMake created? (needless to say, I'm a total beginner in CMake...)

Comment: @Tsyvaref: alright, manually deleting all the CMake output fixed the problem. Thanks a lot! If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Clean reconfiguration is the 0-th step when debug problems with CMake. If you perform out-of-the-source build, you may just clear the build directory (`rm -rf *` in that directory). If you perform in-source build ... well, it is better to avoid such builds.